# Question on Design for User + User Groups + User Types + Subscriptions Model

Tags: mysql, database-design, primary-key, foreign-key

I am redeveloping an existing web application with both weak source code and a weak underlying database design.  I'm trying to develop things in a way that future expansion will be much easier, namely:

- Supporting new login mechanisms
- Supporting new user types (ie new subscriptions plans)
- Supporting new user roles

Here are a few screenshots of my unfinished schema.  Do you see any problems / data inconsistencies that could arise from this design?

Orange squares are primary keys, and blue squares are foreign keys.  Had to split this up into two images.

Users / Subscriptions / Auth Groups:

[image]

User Groups / Subscription Types:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: dis you use a software for the diagram ?

Answer (score 5):

I think you overdid normalization:

- I dont see the purpose of the **user_names** table, i would store the names in the user 
  table
- Same for **basic_user** table, i would store the email and password in the user table as well
- A subscription can have multiple statuses? if not i would put id_status in the subscription table

Comment: Some of the accounts will be created via API, and first and last names will not always be available. That is the reason for storing them separately.  For basic users, a password will be needed, wheras with Facebook users Facebook handles the auth and we just check the Facebook id.  Yep, a subscription can have multiple statuses.  I do think I need to store email in the users table, however, sine all accounts WILL have an email associated with them (even Facebook). Thanks for your feedback!